# Bitmap graphics: when saving on disk no drawed strings - works when memorystream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bitmap, drawstring

I am creating a PNG picture, using the `Bitmap` object, using `Drawing.Graphics` . I create a Bitmap, insert a background image and draw some strings.

**Now, when I save the image on the disk, the files does not have my strings!**

I am doing this in ASP.NET MVC, where this is my controllers signature:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public string GetNewsletterPicture(string headline, string tagline)
```

When I don't save the image on the disk and instead returns a `FileStreamResult` from a `MemoryStream`, the image looks perfectly.

So there is some problem that when I save the image to the disk, the strings are "forgotten" somehow.

Any ideas?

**My code**:

```
ColorConverter converter = new ColorConverter();
        Color textColor = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString("#FF58595B");
        int width = 598;
        int height = 77;
        int offSet = 40;
        int shadowOffset = 1;

        var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.LightGray);
            Image backgroundImg = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/Static/Images/bgimg.png"));
            g.DrawImage(backgroundImg,0,0);

            StringFormat sf= new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            var rectangleTop = new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);
            var rectangleTopShadowHack = new RectangleF(shadowOffset, shadowOffset, width + shadowOffset, height + shadowOffset);
            g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

            // only show headline and center it
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagline))
            {
                var rectangleBottomShadowHack = new RectangleF(shadowOffset, offSet + shadowOffset, width + shadowOffset, height - offSet + shadowOffset);
                var rectangleBottom = new RectangleF(0, offSet, width, height - offSet);

                g.DrawString(tagline, new Font("Verdana", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.White), rectangleBottomShadowHack, sf);
                g.DrawString(tagline, new Font("Verdana", 18), new SolidBrush(textColor), rectangleBottom, sf);
            }
            else
            {
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            }
            g.DrawString(headline, GetFont("Sentinel-Bold", 28, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.White), rectangleTopShadowHack, sf);
            g.DrawString(headline, GetFont("Sentinel-Bold", 28, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(textColor), rectangleTop, sf);

            g.Save();

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Static/Previews/" + fileName);
            bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);

            return fileName;
```

If in doubt, it is the g.DrawString which is not being saved on the picture.

NEW atttempt (still not working):

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public string GetNewsletterPicture(string headline, string tagline)
        {
            ColorConverter converter = new ColorConverter();
            Color textColor = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString("#FF58595B");
            int width = 598;
            int height = 77;
            int offSet = 40;
            int shadowOffset = 1;

            var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.LightGray);
                Image backgroundImg = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/Static/Images/bgimg.png"));
                g.DrawImage(backgroundImg,0,0);

                StringFormat sf= new StringFormat();
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                var rectangleTop = new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);
                var rectangleTopShadowHack = new RectangleF(shadowOffset, shadowOffset, width + shadowOffset, height + shadowOffset);
                g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

                // only show headline and center it
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagline))
                {
                    var rectangleBottomShadowHack = new RectangleF(shadowOffset, offSet + shadowOffset, width + shadowOffset, height - offSet + shadowOffset);
                    var rectangleBottom = new RectangleF(0, offSet, width, height - offSet);

                    g.DrawString(tagline, new Font("Verdana", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.White), rectangleBottomShadowHack, sf);
                    g.DrawString(tagline, new Font("Verdana", 18), new SolidBrush(textColor), rectangleBottom, sf);
                }
                else
                {
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                }
                g.DrawString(headline, GetFont("Sentinel-Bold", 28, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.White), rectangleTopShadowHack, sf);
                g.DrawString(headline, GetFont("Sentinel-Bold", 28, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(textColor), rectangleTop, sf);

                g.Flush(FlushIntention.Sync);
            }

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Static/Previews/" + fileName);
            bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);

            return fileName;


            //MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream();
            //bmp.Save(stm,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            //stm.Position = 0;

            //return new FileStreamResult(stm, "image/png");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure, but it looks like you might be confusing `g.Save()` with `g.Flush()`.

You need to call `g.Flush(FlushIntention.Sync)` instead of `g.Save()`. You should probably also call bmp.Save() *outside* of the using block:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
  //...
  g.Flush(FlushIntention.Sync);
}

var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Static/Previews/" + fileName);

bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png)
```

`Save()` is used to save the current graphics state so that you can modify it and then restore it later.:

```
GraphicsState oldState = g.Save();

// Make some changes to the graphics state...

g.Restore(oldState);
```

`Flush()` on the other hand, is used to force the graphics object to complete any pending operations. By passing `FlushIntention.Sync` as a parameter, `Flush()` won't return until the flushing is complete.

Comment: I just tried to do that.. And I also tried without g.Save() - I have the same problem. Should I not use g.Save() ? There is no more to the snippet than you can see :-) Anyway, no strings still unfortunately

Comment: You should probably also call bmp.Save() outside of the using block. See my edits above.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this (see my new attempt in the original post). Still no luck though! Thanks so much for giving the understanding of save/flush though!

Comment: Just to clarify, the new file you're getting (and I'm assuming you're clearing out the Static/Previews folder so there's no danger of a mixup), still has every bit of graphics adjustment except the strings?